# How to write a SQL query to select batsman wiht highest score than the previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given this table:

```
Name     Score   Year
----------------------
Richie    50     2017
Richie    40     2016
Richie    30     2015
Mark      20     2017
Mark      30     2016
Smith     60     2015
Smith     50     2014
```

Select batsman, score whose score is greater than the previous score.

For example, here the output should be

```
Richie  50   2017
Richie  40   2016
Smith   60   2015
```

I don't know how to get this answer - my attempt so far:

```
select Name, score
from table
order by score ...
```

Output should be

```
Richie  50   2017
Richie  40   2016
Smith   60   2015
```

Comment: Can er be gaps (missing year) or ties (same year) in the year column?

Answer (score 3):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(score) over (partition by name order by year) as prev_score
      from t
     ) t
where score > prev_score;
```

Comment: @user9287446 . . . No.  `lag()` was introduced in SQL Server 2012.  But SQL Server 2008 is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a self join:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on tt.name = t.name and tt.year = t.year - 1
where t.score > tt.score
```

or with exists:

```
select t.*
from tablename t 
where exists(
  select 1 from tablename
  where name = t.name and year = t.year - 1 and score < t.score
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f9dfa70f8ce31379a4bd1dd1e800acba).
Results:

```
> name   | score | year
> :----- | ----: | ---:
> Richie |    50 | 2017
> Richie |    40 | 2016
> Smith  |    60 | 2015
```

Comment: If there is a gap of 2 or more years then that row will not be returned.

Comment: Rich 100 2018
Rich 80 2017
Rich 60 2017
Smith 50 2018
Smith 40 2017
Smith 70 2016
Rich 60 2016



select t.*
from match t 
where exists(
  select 1 from match
  where name = t.name and year = t.year - 1 and score < t.score
)


query outptut

Rich 100 2018
Rich 80 2017
Smith 50 2018

Comment: it does not give expected results ...i need to compare just 20018 with 20017 and 20017 with 2016 etc.. basically if previous years score is less than current year then i need it in the result.Any help is appreciated

Comment: @user9287446 it does give expected results. Check the demo in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use py = (cy.year - 1) or cy = (py.year + 1) in the join, it wouldn't work when there is a gap of 2 or more years.

Try this :

```
select distinct cy.name,cy.score,cy.year from tablename cy 
join tablename py 
on cy.NAME = py.NAME and cy.year > py.year and cy.score > py.score
order by cy.year desc;
```

Results :

```
 NAME                      SCORE       YEAR
-------------------- ---------- ----------
Richie                       50       2017
Richie                       40       2016
Smith                        60       2015
```